# What is the place to view Sitecore module compatibilities

Tags: module

Sitecore comes with lot of official modules. These modules has there own versions while core Sitecore CMS has its own version.

What is the best place to view all these modules and there compatibilities with Sitecore CMS versions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Modules Compatibility Table on Sitecore's knowledge base site: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788.